# PowerShell command missing?

Tags: powershell, github

I am trying to install an CL extension for git called hub https://hub.github.com/

I installed the extension using choco. The following screenshot is showing where it was installed, but when I try to use the command it is trying to access a different path?

I tried to copy hub.exe to the path it is trying to access but am getting the same error. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here or how I can change the path PowerShell goes to?

[image: hub]

Comment: Can you post the output of `Get-Command hub | Select-Object -Property *`? There are more paths than just `Source` ;-) Don't hesitate to post it as code formatted text. It's always better than screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to execute hub.exe:

```
$CommandPath = (Get-Command hub | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Source)
$Command = "$($CommandPath) create"
Invoke-Expression $Command
```